# Crystal report: Count based on date

Tags: sql, templates, crystal-reports, report

currently I'm in midst of developing crystal report template. Any help is much appreciated.

What I want to achieve is to count based on date.

I give example.

I got 3 params:

1. start period(date):  eg: 1/5/2013
2. end period: eg: 5/5/2013(date)
3. how many working days(number): eg: 5

and the table is like this

```
name            working date             
nameA           2/5/2013
                2/5/2013
                3/5/2013

nameB           2/5/2013
                4/5/2013
                5/5/2013
```

I want it to count how many working days for each name.
Eg result: nameA: 2 working days, nameB: 3 working days.

Please help. I'm new to programming..:( Couldn't think any programming design for this..

Comment: You'll want to look into the `DistinctCount()` summary function in CR.

Answer (score 0):

You need this query,

```
select name, count(distinct working_date)
from table where working_date between ? and ?
```

but most of all, you need to learn SQL. It is impossible to write reports without some knowledge of SQL.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer..

however, the table result(working date) is actually coming from database. called using stored procedures.